# SharePoint 2016 on-prem switched to https and Office documents don't open

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, oos

What am I missing or doing incorrect to make SharePoint https work with OOS?Office Online Server on-prem doesn't work opening files from SharePoint if I switch SharePoint 2016 from http to https, but it works fine when SharePoint is using http. To switch web app in Central Admin to https I did it in AAM and I also added the 443 binding in IIS with the SSL cert on the Apps server and I had SharePoint all over working great with https, except that I wasn't able to open any Office document online, getting error in browser "Something went wrong and we couldn't load this content.  Refreshing the browser may fix the problem." 
I have configured SharePoint WopiZone: internal-https and OOS wopi discovery zone: internal-https

-------This is what was registered in the log in the OOS when searching for the error Session ID -----
Wopi,CheckFile,WACSERVER HttpRequestAsyncException [url:UREDACTED_(asdfasdfasldhfjhlkjahdfkaghsd=), e:Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsyncException: No Response in WebException ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---]

Unexpexted:
WOPI CheckFile: Catch-All Failure [exception:Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.UnexpectedErrorException: HttpRequest failed. ---> Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsyncException: No Response in WebException ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.AddHostResponseDataAndThrow(Exception exception, HttpRequestAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException)
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException)
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.End()
 at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.CheckWopiFile()]

Comment: Are you enforcing TLS 1.1 or 1.2 on the SharePoint server (this requires registry edits)? Can you browse to a SharePoint site from the OOS box?

Comment: Thank you Trevor for answering. Yes, I can access SharePoint from the OOS VM with no issues either when I was using https and now with http too. What registry edits do I have to do on the SharePoint server to enforce TLS 1.2?

Comment: on side note, try to reset IIS on SharePoint servers, we had the same issue and simple IIS reset fixed it (about year ago)

Comment: @TrevorSeward for the registry edits, should they be done in both servers if I am using a MinRole Topology with 2 servers? Also, should I follow this article? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-sharepoint-server-2016#NET35x for the registry edits on both servers?

Comment: Thank you Waqas, but I tried resetting IIS as well as restarting the servers and that didn't help neither. I am now following this article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-sharepoint-server-2016 and making sure all the settings are correctly on each server to see if that helps.

Comment: Issue resolved after enforcing TLS1.2 in all SharePoint servers (following Microsoft's article that I posted above), in the OOS server and in my PC,, switching SharePoint AAM in Central Admin to https and restarting IIS in all of them (note that in OOS when trying to do iisreset /noforce it failed but stopped the World Wide Web Publishing Service, so I had to go to Services and start it manually and then start the IIS site that contains the bindings for http and https). Now SharePoint is in https and I can open in browser all Office documents with no issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after enforcing TLS1.2 in all SharePoint servers (following Microsoft's article that I posted above), in the OOS server and in my PC,, switching SharePoint AAM in Central Admin to https and restarting IIS in all of them (note that in OOS when trying to do iisreset /noforce it failed but stopped the World Wide Web Publishing Service, so I had to go to Services and start it manually and then start the IIS site that contains the bindings for http and https). Now SharePoint is in https and I can open in browser all Office documents with no issue at all.